# How to add a python command line tool to my PATH?

Tags: python, pip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I installed the command line tool awsebcli using pip.

```
pip install --upgrade --user awsebcli
```

How do I add this to my PATH so I can just type

```
eb
```

in terminal?

The documentation says this:

> Add an export command to your profile script. The following example
>   adds the path represented by LOCAL_PATH to the current PATH variable.
>
> export PATH=LOCAL_PATH:$PATH

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install.html

But I'm not sure what LOCAL_PATH is here?

```
$ eb --version
-bash: eb: command not found
```

I added that to my .bash_profile and then sourced the file, it still doesn't work as you can see from the above output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, this should work for Linux: `export PATH=$PATH:/.local/bin`. [Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install.html) are some more detailed instructions.